# 'method' on Function.prototype in Douglas Crockford's book

Tags: javascript

In Crockford's book 'method' is added to Function.prototype

In my browser console, I did this

1. `Function.method`
   --> undefined
2. `Function.prototype.method=function(name,func){this.prototype[name]=func; return this;}
   --> function(name,func){this.prototype[ame]=func; return this;}`
3. `(function(){}).method
   --> function(name,func){this.prototype[name]=func; return this;}`
4. `Function.method
   --> function(name,func){this.prototype[name]=func; return this;}`

I can understand step 3, where a function literal has 'method' defined

But how come in step 4, Function.method, which was undefined in step 1, suddenly has 'method' defined.

Is Function an instance of itself ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is Function an instance of itself ?

[Yes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

```
Function instanceof Function;
> true
```